# Running GUI applications from another user, needs write permission for /run/user/1000

Tags: linux, permissions, snap

I didn't want to give access to some sensitive directories when executing proprietary programs from snap. This is what I've done so far:

1. Created a new user and limit read/write access to main `/home` directory and some other directories
2. Added X access to other user for GUI applications,  via `xhost +si:localuser:[user 2]`
3. `su` into the other user and run the command

Unfortunately for some programs write access is required for `/run/user/1000`, which is owned by the main user. For example running `skype` from snap.
What's the problem here? Why doesn't the new user just create a new `run/user` directory? I'm not too familiar with these concepts so a detailed explanation/fix would be very appreciated.

Comment: The short story is that `su` does perform a login.

Comment: `su` or `su -`? Check `env | grep XDG` in the two cases, compare to what it prints for your normal user.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks! your comment was helpful. I updated the question. If you think it's a correct approach, i can close  the question.

Comment: I think it's an acceptable approach. Do not close (whatever you mean). Remove the edit from the question body and [post it as an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks so much! Will do

Answer (score 1):

It seems `su [user 2]` keeps the current shell's environmental variables when switching to another user. To fix this problem, I had to use `su - [user 2]`.
To make sure the new shell works fine, some additional steps are needed after step 2 of original post.

1. Set appropriate `DISPLAY` environmental variable. run `echo $DISPLAY` on [user 1]'s shell. Set the same display for [user 2] as well.  For example by running `export DISPLAY=:0.0` for  [user 2]'s shell.
2. [optional] If you see errors like this in programs like Skype: `cannot create directory '/run/user/1001': Permission denied`, then just create that directory with appropriate permissions and ownership. For example for creating `run/user/1001` run these commands (assuming it doesn't exist):

```bsh
#make sure you're not overriding existing directory properties!
mkdir /run/user/1001
chown -R [user 2]:[user 2]
chmod g-rwx 1001
chmod o-rwx 1001
```

Thanks to the commenters on original post for help with this answer